# perl ptkdb follow into system call

Tags: perl, debugging, system

Im running the ptkdb debugger for Perl.
I am running a script from within a script using the system(); function.
But it's not possible for me to go into the system call, the debugger just jumps over it.
How can i make the debugger actually debug what's going on within the system call?

Answer (score 2):

system() forks a process and runs it as a shell command.  The Perl debugger will not follow from a Perl parent process to a forked shell command.

Steps you could use to debug this part:

1)  You could debug the shell call itself, is it doing what you're expecting it to do?  (Running it manually, running it from strace/dtrace)

2)  You could print any variables you're sending to it.  Are your variables being passed correctly?

3)  You can check the return of the command to see if it's doing what you want.

Also, are you sure system() is what you want?  From the perldoc system:

> This is not what you want to use to
>   capture the output from a command, for
>   that you should use merely backticks
>   or qx//, as described in `STRING` in
>   perlop. Return value of -1 indicates a
>   failure to start the program or an
>   error of the wait(2) system call
>   (inspect $! for the reason).

Comment: yes im sure its what i want, sometimes its necessary to create child processes and then it would be convenient to be able to debug them.

Comment: [The debugger *does* follow the forked child process!](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/lib/perl5db.pl#xterm_get_fork_TTY) Just try it, you'll get a xterm window.